# OCR for correct indentation to a .txt file

Tags: ocr, text

I have a lot of scans of documents in which spaces and indentation are important, and I am trying to find an OCR solution that would correctly process the formatting with an output of a .txt file. So far I have tried tesseract and google cloud vision (both work poorly with formatting) as well as abbyy Finereader (the best solution so far, the formatting is preserved with .docx and .rtf output but, but isn't for .txt files)

Comment: Are you looking for a library to create an application with this, or something end-user ready?  Do you have a budget or are you looking for something available at no cost?

Comment: All solutions are welcome.

Comment: Welcome! Do you have an OS requirement?

Comment: Preferably windows

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:  I work for the company which creates these products.**

If you're looking to develop a commercial product, the LEADTOOLS SDK can output to text with an option to insert spaces to try to retain the layout of the input page.
https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/ft/textdocumentoptions.html

```
public static void WriteText(string inputFilename, string outputFilename)
{
 IOcrEngine ocrEngine = OcrEngineManager.CreateEngine(OcrEngineType.LEAD);
 ocrEngine.Startup(null, null, null, null);

 using (IOcrDocument document = ocrEngine.DocumentManager.CreateDocument())
 {
    IOcrPage page = document.Pages.AddPage(inputFilename, null);
    page.AutoZone(null);
    page.Recognize(null);

    TextDocumentOptions options = ocrEngine.DocumentWriterInstance.GetOptions(DocumentFormat.Text) as TextDocumentOptions;
    options.Formatted = true;

    ocrEngine.DocumentWriterInstance.SetOptions(DocumentFormat.Text, options);

    document.Save(outputFilename, DocumentFormat.Text, null);
 }

 ocrEngine.Shutdown();
}
```

[image]
In the above screenshot, the original TIFF laid out in columns can be seen in the background, with the exported text document displayed in notepad.

The toolkit is available for evaluation at http://www.leadtools.com

If you'd prefer something end-user ready, ePrint can also perform this conversion.
https://eprintdriver.com/

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to add an example image (text with various indentations) and the OCR'd result?